# How do you actually calculate the conditional expectation in this question?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm taking a course in probability theory and I've come across the following question:

---

Let $\Omega = (0,\infty)$ and $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{B}((0,\infty))$. Given some $\lambda > 0$ let $\mathbb{P}$ be defined such that $\mathbb{P}((a,b]) = e^{-\lambda a} - e^{-\lambda b}$ (for $0<a<b$). Let:

$$X(\omega) = \omega, \ \ Y(\omega) = \text{min}\{\omega, k\}$$ For some $k > 0$.

**Q. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[X | \sigma(Y)]$**

---

The issue is that I only know what conditional expectation is in terms of its theoretical definition, as a random variable (the same goes for the sigma algebra generated by a variable, such as $Y$ as above). One of my friends has communicated to me the following idea: $$\mathbb{E}[X | \sigma(Y)] = Y\mathbb{1}_{\{Y < k\}} + \dfrac{1}{e^{\lambda k}} \int_k^{\infty} \omega d(1 - e^{-\lambda \omega})\mathbb{1}_{\{Y = k\}}$$ However, I do not understand how one arrives at the expression on the right via the expression on the left. Could somebody help me out and perhaps show me the slower version of how we go from left to right here?

Comment: In fact, I have also noticed that $\sigma(Y)$ must be defined by the sets $(0,k)$ and $[k,\infty]$, right? In this case, the conditional expectation is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable if and only if it has the form as above. However, I still don't understand how you get the coefficients of the indicators. Also I don't get why $X$ isn't just measurable by $Y$ since $\sigma(Y)$ surely contains $(0,\infty)$, right?

Comment: We are missing your definition of conditional expectation. What is it?

Comment: You probably need a more conceptual approach rather than formal definitions. In probability theory sigma algebras provides information about the randomness modelled in the probability space. In particular, $\sigma(Y)$ contains the information that can be understood by knowing the outcome of Y. Therefore, again using a conceptual approach, $E[X| \sigma(Y)]$ can be viewed as the expectation you have on X given you know the outcome of Y. Say k=10. If i tell you Y=5 then it must be $\omega=5$ for which X=5. This means that if I tell you the value of Y and this is less then k, i am telling you...

Comment: ...the value of $\omega$. Therefore you know what X is going to be hence you expect exactly the value of X. This make the first added. If Y=k, this is means $\omega \geq k$, therefore you dont know exactly the value of X (as in the other case) but you know that it is not less than k. Then, in this case, your best estimate on X is the expectation of X clearly assuming $\omega \geq k$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It makes sense now and I prefer this intuitive approach much more